# Edit the href link before send the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XxMgW/) code :

```
<a class="myLink" href='http://www.website.it/'>Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var stringToSend = "";
    $('.myLink').click(function() {
        stringToSend="?param=1";
    }); 
</script>
```

and, as you can see, I'd like to add `stringToSend` to the href (so the request will be at http://www.website.it/?param=1).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just modify the `href` with new `href` and you are done.

```
$('.myLink').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", this.href + "?param=1");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also prevent the default behavior like this:

```js
var stringToSend = "";

// Use this to actually navigate to the changed Uri
$('.myLink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    stringToSend = "?param=1";
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + stringToSend;
}); 

// Use this just to change the Href, without navigating to uri
$('.myLink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    stringToSend = "?param=1";
    var newUri = $(this).attr('href') + stringToSend;
    $(this).attr("href", newUri);
});
```

Comment: ? Is what I'd like to avoid. I wont use windows.location.href... :)

Comment: event.preventDefault();
stringToSend = "?param=1"; 
var newUri = $(this).attr('href') + stringToSend;
$(this).attr('href', newUri);

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting, I will just move it up to the original comment

Comment: Yes, but why prevent default is my intention is to navigate to the edited link? :)

Comment: Well you should have explained better your requirements. It sounds more like: "I'd like to navigate to the original href + some parameter without using a location.href assignment."

Answer (score 1):

When clicking, you could stop the current URL, and navigate to another:

```
var stringToSend = "";
$('.myLink').click(function() {
    stringToSend="?param=1";
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + stringToSend; // navigate to new URL
    return false; // abort navigation to URL from <a>
});
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it :) I think the "stringToSend" variable is redundant though

Comment: @Richard H: You're correct. If it's a static string then it can be put inline as well.

Comment: Many peoples suggest that window.location.href. I'll avoid this. a href is made for this use, why use location href? ShankarSangoli is the best way imo...

Comment: @markzzz: I was thinking that altering `href` when you click the link was too late. I stand corrected, it's a better solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the window.location on your click, and return false to prevent the default behaviour.

A such:

```
<a class="myLink" href='http://www.website.it/'>Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var stringToSend = "";
    $('.myLink').click(function() {
        window.location.href = this.href + "?param=" + stringToSend;
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```