# How to pass value to other page when click an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I am begineer of Perl. I'd like to ask how to pass value to other page when clicking an anchor tag?

The part of code are:

```
# ...
$cq = new CGI; 
$cq->param('user');  
# ...
$htmlout.='<form name="mainform" method="POST" action="/scripts/yyyy.plex">';
$htmlout.='<input type="text" name="user" value="'.$user.'"/>';
$htmlout.='<a href="/scripts/xxxx.plex">Link to Page A</a>';
$htmlout.='<input type="submit" name="pageB" value="Click to Page B"/>';
# ...
print $htmlout;
```

I want to pass the value that user keyin can retain on every page, I try to use `$cq->param('user')` or pass in url but only work on Page B, any way I can get the value that user keyin after click the link to Page A?(without ajax)

note: Labels have the name "user" exist every other page.

[image: It look like this]

Comment: You will need to add an on-click handler to the link, read the value form the text field and append it to the link's `href` attribute. There is a good explanation on how to do that with jQuery in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159254/1331451).

Comment: Write out a `<input type="hidden" ...>` tag? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If you want to retain a value from page to page throughout a browsing session, you should be looking at cookies, not passing values from page to page using forms or URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Produce the following output from your script:

```
<a href="/scripts/xxxx.plex?foo=bar">Link to Page A</a>
```

If the value isn't known when you build the page, you'll need to use JavaScript (to build the URL or to submit a form).

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['mainform'].submit()">Link to Page A</a>
```